# Need a good way to ssh into a pc and run tmux

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko, tmux

I want to SSH into a pc from python code and start tmux and attach to the session and run my programs.
I tryd useing paramiko, if i run tmux it crasched beacause it could not attach to session. Only way i could create a session in paramiko is to run

```
"tmux new-session -s <pannel name> -d"
```

but problem is still that i cant attach to the session useing

`tmux a`

The solution i have atm is autopygui python library and useing putty to start the process this solution works, but i need a better solution.

Comment: Why aren't you able to attach? Have you tried listing the sessions (`tmux list-sessions`) to see if one is available? You can't close the shell inside tmux with `exit` or `Ctrl+D`, you've got to exit via sighup or `Ctrl + A D` (I forget if it's `Ctrl +A` or `Ctrl + B`, I always customize it because I run nested Tmux sessions when SSHing). It sounds like you aren't able to attach because there's no sessions available.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh The way i think paramiko works is that somehow it sends commands to the main terminal useing tmux creates a new session not on the main terminal so when i run `tmux` the new session is created but it crashes because it cant attach to session. If i run `tmux new-session -s <pannel name> -d` and i the run `tmux a` i get the same error but tmux is "alive"

Answer (score 1):

Found an solution on [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409861/is-it-possible-to-send-input-to-a-tmux-session-without-connecting-to-it) since i cant find it on stack overflow i will post it here.

as part of the question with SSH i used paramiko, [template](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-ssh-using-paramiko-in-python) here for the paramiko SSH code. In commands array just enter the tmux commands below.

for terminal commands i used

1. Create a detached session:

   `tmux new -d -s mySession`
2. Execute a command in the detached session:

   `tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "echo 'Hello World'" ENTER`

3.1 Attach to the session

```
`tmux a -t mySession`
```

3.2 To exit SSH terminal

```
exit
```

**Solution explanation:**

Paramiko can't attach/jump to the new session with paramiko so solution is to use sendkeys in detached mode to execute commands.